# what is config-mode in kubeconfig file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeconfig, kubernetes-rbac

I see there is a field "config-mode" in Kubernetes configuration file (kubeconfig).

```
users:
- name: myuser
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: xxxxx
        apiserver-id: xxxxx
        client-id: xxxxx
        config-mode: "1"
        environment: PublicCloud
        expires-in: "xxxx"
        expires-on: "xxxxxxx"
        refresh-token: xxxxxx
        tenant-id: xxxxxx
      name: user1
```

What is the use of this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is flag specific for azure. 
Here is a quote from kubernetes CHANGELOG page:

> Added a config-mode flag in azure auth module to enable getting AAD token without spn: prefix in audience claim. 
> When it's not specified, the default behavior doesn't change. 
> (#87630, @weinong) [SIG API Machinery, Auth, CLI and Cloud Provider]

[Reference to the changelog page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d41249f780316841a0e13948e7af24d10b9c9c0d/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.18.md) 
[Reference to the PR that added this flag](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87630/files)